# zeros of Incomplet Gamma function

Tags: gamma-function, riemann-zeta

for which values of complex variable  $z$  let us  getting  the zeros of incomplet gamma

function ($\Gamma(0.5,z)$)   ?

I would be interest for any replies or any comments

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?s=38&_=1404607786799&i=complex+roots+Gamma%5b0.5%2cz%5d&fp=1&incTime=true

Comment: ok, r there obvious conditions about the complex varible z ?

Comment: @TylerHG : these are not zeroes but misinterpretations of underflows.

Answer (score 1):

There are simply no zero for $\Gamma(1/2 , 0)$.